# How to name checked list box in C# dynamically?

Tags: c#

The names shouldn't change even when checked list boxes are sorted.
I tried to name them by using just concatenating strings but that didn't work at last. I need to name them like a id like "Polygon 1 , 2 etc " and display them accordingly.

Comment: What didn't work with concatenating strings? This should work: _CheckBox cb = new CheckBox {Name = "firstCb"};_ The name property can be determined dynamically.

Comment: string namei = i.ToString();
i++;
                    string name = "polygon" + namei;

Like this

Comment: i got it tnks the below one helped me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code set name of all  `CheckBoxes` dynamically (WinForms):

```
public Form1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     CheckBox[] chk = new CheckBox[10];
     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     {
         chk[i] = new CheckBox();
         chk[i].Name = "Polygon " + i + 1;
         //Rest of your code
     }
}
```

for `CheckBoxList` something like this (Web Application):

```
CheckBoxList chkList = new CheckBoxList();
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.ID = "Polygon1";
chkList.Items.Add("chk");
myDiv.Controls.Add(chkList);
```

Comment: checked ist box not checkbox.. im not getting any .Name for checked list box

Comment: if i had to display this name how to i display i.e whhile adding it to the checkedlistbox window    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(name);

Comment: `checkedListBox1.Items.Add(string item);` like this: `checkedListBox1.Items.Add("your item");`